Importing applicationgateway with Terraform changes id,rules,replacing in plan
I am trying to import an existing Azure application gateway with terraform.
I created dynamic blocks to make it general,using modules for different environments.
I have a tfvars where I have the variables there and when I am doing the import it finds them but it wants to change the rules with other names,or descending order,he wants to replace them with some other value.
Got any idea?
Created a tfvars file with all the names the values of the already deployed application gateway.
      dynamic "rewrite_rule_set" {
        for_each = var.rewrite_rule_sets
        content {
          name = rewrite_rule_set.value["name"]
          dynamic "rewrite_rule" {
            for_each = rewrite_rule_set.value["rewrite_rule"]
            content {
              name          = rewrite_rule.value["name"]
              rule_sequence = rewrite_rule.value["rule_sequence"]
              dynamic "condition" {
                for_each = rewrite_rule.value["condition"]
                content {
                  variable    = condition.value["variable"]
                  pattern     = condition.value["pattern"]
                  ignore_case = condition.value["ignore_case"]
                  negate      = condition.value["negate"]
                }
              }

and variables
    variable "rewrite_rule_sets" {
      type = map(object({
        name = string
        rewrite_rule = optional(map(object({
          name          = string
          rule_sequence = string
          condition = optional(map(object({
            variable    = string
            pattern     = string
            ignore_case = optional(bool)
            negate      = optional(bool)
          })))
          request_header_configuration = optional(map(object({
            header_name  = string
            header_value = string
          })))
          response_header_configuration = optional(map(object({
            header_name  = string
            header_value = string
          })))
          url = optional(map(object({
            path         = optional(string)
            query_string = optional(string)
            components   = optional(string)
            reroute      = optional(bool)
          })))
        })))
      }))
    }


It would help if you could show us some Terraform code.

Added it sorry,
